# React Native : From within DrawerNavigator's contentComponent, how to exit DrawerNavigator completely to other screen component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem to navigate away from a drawer navigator's content component

Nav's (navigator root screen component) render()

```
render() {
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
            Home : {screen : Home},
            Settings : {screen : Settings}
        },{
            contentComponent: DrawerContent,
            drawerWidth: 200,
            drawerPosition: 'left',
            drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
            drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
            drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
    });
    return (<Drawer/>);
}
```

DrawerContent's render()

```
render() {return (<FlatList 
    data : ['Home', 'Settings', 'Logout'],
    renderItem : {({item, index}) => {
        return (<Button
            title = {item} 
            onPress = {() => {
                if(index != 2) this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: item}));
                else this.pleaseTakeMeOutOfHere();
            }}
        />);
    }}
/>)}
```

Suppose I want to get out from Nav to an external screen component called Login, how I should define pleaseTakeMeOutOfHere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I export to the parent navigator (like `StackNavigator` or `SwitchNavigator`), the component which render the `DrawerNavigator` as a child like I did in the question, calling `this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');` from `contentComponent` not working at all. I don't know why. I guess because the navigation chain is broken by doing such. I can't even remember why I did that. I've finally fixed it by export the `DrawerNavigator` directly

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({...},{...});
export default Drawer;
```

And to exit the `DrawerNavigator` instead of adding it to the stack, I have to replace `StackNavigator` with `SwitchNavigator`. Thanks to Pritish Vaidya for the answer

Though this question is specific to my case, I hope anyone will get an idea from here when they face the same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to use a [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#switchnavigatorconfig) for this.

You can define two stacks for this `LoginStack`, `HomeStack`.

```
export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    LoginStack: LoginStack,
    HomeStack: HomeStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeStack',
  }
);
```

and then use  `this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeStack');` to navigate out of `LoginStack`

Switch navigator *does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away*.

Comment: I've already use StackNavigator. Is that ok if I replace that StackNavigator with SwitchNavigator?

Comment: You can nest `Stack` inside `Switch` too. The `LoginStack` and` HomeStack` are instance of a `StackNavigator`